# How to use joins in Cassandra database?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

i am using Cassandra database. i am unable to use multiple queries and combining two tables values like join. is there any way to achieve joins in Cassandra

Answer (score 5):

No, Cassandra doesn't support joins directly - you need to perform joins on application level.  You may use Spark's SQL support to perform joins, but it will be much slower.

Comment: application level means? i need to perform 2 queries and concatenate there?

Comment: surely there is no other way to do it inside cassandra?

Comment: Cassandra, as many other NoSQL databases doesn't support joins - they are not scalable as you need to hit other tables that could be on different nodes. If you rework your data model then you can avoid joins at all. Here are some hints: https://opencredo.com/how-not-to-use-cassandra-like-an-rdbms-and-what-will-happen-if-you-do/